# XML Schema enforce child elements without enforcing tag name

Tags: xml, xsd

I trying to make a schema for the following xml.

```
<root>
    <allow_any_name id="string">
        <required_tag_1>string</required_tag_1>
        <required_tag_2>string</required_tag_2>
        <required_tag_3>string</required_tag_3>
    </allow_any_name>

    <name1 id="string">
        <required_tag_1>string</required_tag_1>
        <required_tag_2>string</required_tag_2>
        <required_tag_3>string</required_tag_3>
    </name1>

    <name2 id="string">
        <required_tag_1>string</required_tag_1>
        <required_tag_2>string</required_tag_2>
        <required_tag_3>string</required_tag_3>
    </name2>

</root>
```

The main problem is that I can't find a way to specify the child elements with any specifying the tag name as well.  In the above xml the `allow_any_name` tag could be any name.

I have tried `<xs:any processContents="lax"></xs:any>` which allow any tag name but does not allow me to specify the children.

I also tried using `<xs:any processContents="strict" namespace="##local"></xs:any>` which enforces the child elements but means I have to know all the tag names used (which I don't)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with XSD 1.0.

In XSD 1.1 it can be done using assertions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with XML Schema.
I think you must change your structure from

```
<allow_any_name id="string">
  <required_tag_1>string</required_tag_1>
  <required_tag_2>string</required_tag_2>
  <required_tag_3>string</required_tag_3>
</allow_any_name>
```

to something like this:

```
<fixed_tag_name id="string" name="allow_any_name">
  <required_tag_1>string</required_tag_1>
  <required_tag_2>string</required_tag_2>
  <required_tag_3>string</required_tag_3>
</fixed_tag_name>
```

hth